# error: target file "./scripts/target.json" does not exist

Tags: rust, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I'm compile the Linux kernel module but I get the follow error

```sh
error: target file "./scripts/target.json" does not exist

make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:292: /home/guilherme/repositories/rust_learn/hello_world_lkm/hello_world.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/home/guilherme/repositories/linux/Makefile:1913: /home/guilherme/repositories/rust_learn/hello_world_lkm] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Saindo do diretório '/home/guilherme/repositories/linux'
```

The module is a Rust module, and I'm doing this for a studying purposes. I dont have a lot knowning in Rust, but I study this. I have a short experience in Linux kernel module in C and I starting this in Rust.

I has a Rust installed in my computer:

```sh
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.73.0 (cc66ad468 2023-10-03)
```

and I have a `cargo` installed:

```sh
$ cargo --version
cargo 1.73.0 (9c4383fb5 2023-08-26)
```

I has a RUST cofigured in my kernel: [image: make menuconfig]

The module that I'm developing is very simple:

```rust
use kernel::prelude::*

module! {
    type: HelloWorld,
    name: b"HelloWorld",
    license b"GPL"
};

struct HelloWorld;

impl kernel::Module for HelloWorld {
    fn init(_name: &'static CStr, _module: &'static ThisModule) -> Result<Self> {
        pr_info!("Hello world");
        Ok(HelloWorld) 
    }
}

impl Drop for HelloWorld {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        pr_info!("Adeus mundo cruel fdp");
    }
}
```

and my Makefile is very simple too:

```makefile
PWD   := $(shell pwd)
obj-m += hello_world.o

CLANG ?= clang
ifeq ($(origin CC),default)
CC := ${CLANG}
endif

all:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) CC=$(CC) CONFIG_CC_IS_CLANG=y modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) clean
```

I have a `clang` installed:

```sh
$ clang --version
clang version 16.0.6
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

And Rust is available in my kernel source:

```sh
$ make LLVM=1 rustavailable
Rust is available!
```

Comment: You should [replace that image of text with it's text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).